# Build a new page through jQuery or redirect if p:contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conditional-statements

I have a tumblr blog. One of the downside is that they don't let you customize the 404 error page. Since I'm new to jQuery it took me quite some searches and reading just to get these lines down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("p:contains(The URL you requested could not be found.)").closest('body').remove();

        });
</script>
```

Anyway I'm not sure if this brought me closer. Tumblr have no function that detects if the page exists or not. It simply displays a paragraph "The URL you requested..". So to customize it I'd have to select the page with that string and delete everything that's already in there. The next step is to put the things I want in there. But here's where I get stuck and my question is: Is there anyway to rebuild a page through jQuery? Like the ".html('') functon?

If not, is it possible to set up a condition that checks if the current page has a string containing "The URL you...." and if true, redirect the user to another page? I tried doing:

```
        if($("p:contains(The URL you requested could not be found.)")) {
                    alert('Test')
```

But that function fired on every page, Error 404 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($("p:contains(The URL you requested could not be found.)").length>0) {
                  window.location.href='newurl';
```

Comment: $() will return an array. because that you must ask exactly if in array $() are any elements - property `length` contain number of elements in array and we must check if it's greater than 0